# JS click event on multiple classes

Tags: javascript

A little stuck here with the following code that works opening a modal on click with the class name '.pl-modal', however when using the class in multiple places it only works on the first element.

I'd like to understand why it doesn't work on multiple elements with the same class.

```js
let player = null;
const $ = function (el) {
  return document.querySelector(el);
};
$(document).on("click", function () {
  $(".pl-modal").classList.add("pl-modal-active");
  player.playVideo();
},false);

function popupClose() {
  $(".pl-modal").classList.remove("pl-modal-active");
  $(".pl-hidden").style.display = "block";
  player.stopVideo();
  player.setPlaybackRate(1);
}
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target == $(".pl-modal")) {
    popupClose();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query selector all and foreach:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.class1').forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(event.target.innerText);
}));
```

```html
<div class="class1">text1</div>
<div class="class1">text2</div>
<div class="class1">text3</div>
```

Read [here](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-add-event-listener-multiple-elements-javascript/) for more

Answer (score 0):

You have to use document.querySelectorAll instead of document.querySelector. querySelector only returns the first element.